# Spring tool suite 4 cannot run with updated application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I find that once I change the application.properties, then in eclipse spring tool suite 4, right click the main class, and run as > spring boot app, it still use the content of previous applicaiton.properties.

Everytime I change the content of application.properties, I need right click the project, choose maven > update project.

Then all resources is erased in {project}\target\classes, and I need to run as > maven test to generate the resources to target\classes and generated-sources, generated-test-sources folder.

any method to let spring tool suite to automatically use my updated application-properties?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in m2e:https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/1150

Here is the corresponding issue in the Spring Tools issue tracker: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/929

I expect the fix to be released as part of m2e 2.2.0 and to be included in the upcoming Eclipse 2023-03 release + the upcoming Spring Tools 4.18.0 release.

If you want to give early snapshots a try, you can download the latest CI build of the Spring Tool Suite for Eclipse 2023-03, which is based on the latest milestones of Eclipse 2023-03 and m2e 2.2.0: https://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS4/nightly-distributions.html